# Can we add condition in where clause through php to sphinx?

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I have 3 tables and performing `JOIN` operation on them with the help of `AND` condition in sphinx. When I fire the same query in `mysql`, it gives me 25 results (12 for Deer, 10 for Dog and 3 for Crow). Deer, Dog and Crow are part of the same column '`animal_name`'. Indeed, in those 3 tables data is huge and it should return more than 1200 results but giving only 25 results.

Now, what I want to do is, I just want to get results for any of the above type of animal name and hence, want to pass additional condition with where clause something like `"Where animal_name = 'Deer'"` in php code. When I try this but it gives 12 results only which is same as mysql query without passing animal name in where clause.

Sample query

```
Select UUID_SHORT() AS sphinxid, t1.animal_name, t1.column_name1, t3.column_name2 from table1 t1, table2 t2,  table3 t3 
where 
t1.id = t2.id AND 
t2.id = t3.id; //want to add condition AND t1.animal_name = 'Deer' via php
```

Please help me I think my query is correct for sphinx indexing only problem is not appending `AND` condition via php code and there is the problem.

Comment: your going to have to show us what the query you think is correct looks like, I didn't know sphinx could do a join.  Typically in a NOSQL system you would de-normalize the data. ( flatten it out )

Comment: Reference query edited question. Even I am new to Sphinx, mysql and php

Comment: try using 'case' which worked in MySql!!
I haven't tried sphinx.

Comment: That woudn't be they way i would do a join, but guess i'm just old school...

Comment: Honestly dont understand what trying to do here. 'Add via php' doesnt really make sence. If you edit the query in `sql_query,` it affects what data IS written to the INDEX. To create dynamic 'filtered' views of the data, you change the `sphinx` query. Perhaps specify WHAT you trying to archive, rather than the minutiae of what you have tried. We dont understand the 'big picture' as ios

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question directly "Can we add condition in where clause through php to sphinx?" the simplest equivalent for "Where animal_name = 'Deer'" is probably

```
$cl->Query('Deer', 'index_name');
```

But from

> in those 3 tables data is huge and it should return more than 1200
>   results but giving only 25 results

I guess you perhaps want to do UNION in your mysql query, not AND. This well may be the reason why "it should return more than 1200 results but giving only 25 results"